# Sidekiq Alternatives for Queuing and Multithreading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, sidekiq, resque, queuing

I need some Rails application server for queuing some processes and run them in multiple threads simultaneously. I find Sidekiq too expensive for my purposes and I'm looking for an alternative. Can I run multiple threads with Resque? Should I use sucker_punch or Shoryuken? Thanks in advance!

**-- UPDATED --**

See answer in comments below.

Comment: What do you mean, sidekiq is expensive? It's free.

Comment: But I need to run several processes and you need the Enterprise option for that (http://sidekiq.org/)

Comment: Nope, you can run as many sidekiq processes as you want in the free version. It just requires a bit more work from you, that's all.